# Showing that $A=\{n(n+1)/2; n\in\mathbb N\}$ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that $A=\{\,\frac{n(n+1)}2\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}$
 is countably infinite.
I know that to solve it I have to show that there exists an injective $f:M \to N$, but I don't know how the algorithm for showing it works. Big thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: Since $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ you get an injective map $f\colon A\mathbb N$ simply by choosing $f(x)=x$ for each $a\in A$. You also have an injection $g\colon\mathbb N\to A$ given by $g(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}2$. Maybe you could clarify you post a little bit; it is not clear in what relation is the set $A$ to the sets $M$ and $N$ you mention in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\frac{1}{2}n (n+1)$ and solve for positive $m$, giving $\nu(m) = \frac{1}{2}(-1 + \sqrt{1+8m})$. Then $\nu$ is a bijection  from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (surjectivity is by construction - it is straightforward to show $\nu(\frac{1}{2}n (n+1)) = n$, injectivity follows since $\nu$ is strictly increasing).

Answer (score 1):

The map $\mathbb N\to A$, $n\mapsto \frac{n(n+1)}2$ is obviously surjective.
But it is also injective because
$$\begin{align} \frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{m(m+1)}2&\implies n(n+1)=m(m+1)\\&\implies n^2-m^2+n-m=0\\&\implies (n-m)(n+m+1)=0\\&\implies n-m=0\lor n+m+1=0\implies n=m.\end{align}$$